# Website not working after deployment

Tags: php, github, laravel-5

My website works fine in a local environment but after creating a repo on Github and pushing the files to a cloud server, I get a whole bunch of Vendor/ related errors? Even though the /Vendor folder is included inside .gitignore

My best guess is that I'm missing some essential steps between DEV and PROD?

The error being displayed is: "array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given"

See attached screenshot for further information:

[image]

Comment: Since you've mentioned vendor so you're using Composer. try doing a composer update on your live server. Also, post your codes not screenshots.

Comment: My server is already running multiple Laravel applications, does this rule out the need to update composer?

Comment: go to the specific project and do the composer udpate there. The code in your question is inside the vendor folder so it's composer related.

Answer (score 0):

Error you getting related to Vendor, So I think something is missing in vendor.

1. Lets rename vendor to vendor_old
2. run `composer install`  - Make sure installation processed successfully.
3. run `php artisan cache:clear`

I hope this works for you.